# Web Audio Api - start() function is not recognized

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, declaration, web-audio-api

I am currently working on a Step Sequencer. For playing back the sequence I have programmed a function playSequence() that gets called when I press the start button on my HTML-Web Page. Everything worked perfectly fine when I implemented the function like this:

```
function playSequence() {

    samplePlayer = [ctx.createBufferSource(), ctx.createBufferSource(), ctx.createBufferSource(),
        ctx.createBufferSource(), ctx.createBufferSource()]

        playHead %= rhythm[0].length;
        for (let i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
            if (rhythm[i].charAt(playHead) == '1') {
                samplePlayer[i].connect(ctx.destination);
                samplePlayer[i].buffer = samples[i];
                samplePlayer[i].start(ctx.currentTime);
            }
        }
        playHead++;
        setTimeout(playSequence, 1000 / (document.getElementById("bpm").value / 60 * 4));
}
```

As you can see, I am manually creating all BufferSources in the samplePlayer Array.
Now I wanna do this dynamically, so that I can change the amount of samples loaded later on while using the web application.
To achieve this I changed the code like this:

```
function playSequence() {

        playHead %= rhythm[0].length;
        for (let i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
            if (rhythm[i].charAt(playHead) == '1') {
                samplePlayer[i] = ctx.createBufferSource();
                samplePlayer[i].connect(ctx.destination);
                samplePlayer[i].buffer = samples[i];
                samplePlayer[i].start(ctx.currentTime);
            }
        }
        playHead++;
        setTimeout(playSequence, 1000 / (document.getElementById("bpm").value / 60 * 4));
}
```

The problem now is, that start() is not recognized as a function anymore. I see that because the Editor I am using is not displaying the function in yellow color anymore (which it normally does).

I would be really happy if someone could help me out with this one! Please let me know if the code is incomprehensible because of the missing explanation to the global variables.

Best wishes!

Comment: In your new example, you aren't declaring `samplePlayer` at all? Try `var samplePlayer = {};` (yes, an object instead of an array, as you're basically using it as an object). Also, you probably shouldn't be creating new nodes for each new note encountered to be more efficient...

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply. The question i asked is actually wrong, the code did work properly, it was only my text editor that was not styling the code correctly. The declaration of `samplePlayer` does happen as a global variable outside the function. I'll try making the code more efficient based on your tip.